# Keep track of tasks submitted to ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, executor, futuretask

I am running several tasks in a ThreadPoolExecutor. I initialise it as follows:

```
private VideoExportExecutor executor;
private BlockingQueue<Runnable> jobQueue;

public void initialiseVideoProcessor()
{
    jobQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
    executor = new VideoExportExecutor(1, 1, Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS, jobQueue);
}
```

I have made my own implementation of runnable (`VideoExportThread`) which contains a `getProgress()` method to keep track of the progress of submitted tasks. I submit instances of this as follows:

```
executor.submit(new VideoExportThread(gcmPath));
```

I am after a way to query the executor/blockingQueue for current/pending threads. I have tried to use `jobQueue.toArray()` and to override the executor method `beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r)` but in both cases the returned runnable is of type FutureTask which does not contain much data. Is there a way for me to use it to retrieve my original `VideoExportThread` instance in order to identify which ones are running and to query its progress?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply keep a list of your Runnables?

```
List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<> ();
VideoExportThread r = new VideoExportThread(gcmPath);
runnables.add(r);
executor.submit(r);
```

Also note that `executor.submit(r);` returns a `Future` - you can call its `isDone()` method to check if the submitted task is still running.

---

Side comment: there might be a good reason to manage the job queue manually, but if not, you use one of the factory methods to make your life easier. For example: `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();`.

Comment: That is what I will end up doing. I think it would have been cleaner to query the executor/blockingList directly but this will do the job. Thanks.